# Login using encrypted_password with devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails 4.X app using devise and devise_token_auth. I want to encrypt the email and password while calling this app.

Here is the server side code:

## user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

## Gemfile

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'omniauth'
```

This is my curl call (with username and password in clear text)

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/sign_in -d "{\"email\":\"user@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"aaaaaaa"}"
```

I know I can use https to secure the initial call. But is there any other way to send the user name and password encrypted (without using https)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could implement [challenge-response authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication) as specified in [RFC 7616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616). This would protect the password sufficiently over a plaintext channel. However, this method is inherently prone to [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Another issue is that this method relies on a shared secret which is impairing safe storage of the password on the server side.

My advice were to use the basic authentication scheme as specified in [RFC 7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617) over a secure channel (i.e. https). This is relatively easy to implement and established practice.